# Calculus Critical points (inner & boundary) multivariable

Tags: calculus

I have this assignment I need help with, it follows:

We have the function: $$f(x,y)=\frac{(1+3xy)}{(1+x^2+y^2)}$$

for all $(x,y)$ in the closed disk $C$ with radius 2 and its center in $(x,y)=(0,0) \in \Bbb{R}^2$

1. Find and decide all critical points inside $f$.
2. Do a parametrization of $C$ to find all extreme points on the boundary.
3. Use Lagrange method to find all candidates for extreme points on the boundary of $C$.
4. Use the result of the previous points to find all extreme points for $f$.

So I've solved the first, I think. I first derivated the function for $x$ and then for $y$, and I got that the only critical point inside $f$ is $(0,0)$.

But on point 2) I get stuck, I'm not sure if I'm on the right track, but I believe what I have to do is since the disk has radius 2, I have to write it as $x^2+y^2=4$, and then parameterize it as $2\cos t+2\sin t=4$? But after that then what?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think using sines and cosines will help. Let $g(x,y)=x^2+y^2-4$ and then use Lagrange multipliers: $\nabla f=\lambda \nabla g$.

Comment: Alright, I'll try that, thanks :)

Comment: Just a quesiton, you have the gradient sign infront of f and g, does it mean that I have you take their derivatives? I thought the function alone was enough?

Comment: Yes, both functions. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier

Comment: EDIT: check b again, I have to do a parameterization..

Comment: @Eulersfunction Well, you can do the $x = \rho \cos t$, $y = \rho \sin t$ param. and apply it to $f$ as well, then set $\rho = 2$ and you end up with a one-variable $f(t)$.

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you mean, but I solved b now, I'm on c, but I can't seem to successfully apply lagrange method, any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to solve 2., which uses a parametrization, is as follows: parametrize the circle as $x=2\cos t$, $y=2\sin t$, $0\leq t\leq 2\pi$. Then your function $f$ becomes a function of one variable, call it $h$: $$h(t)=f(x(t),y(t))=\frac{1+12\cos t\sin t}{5}, \; 0\leq t\leq 2\pi.$$ You can now find the extrema of this functions using one-variable calculus. The critipal points you'll find might be different than the ones obtained with the Lagrange multiplier method, but the max/min should be exactly the same.

Comment: Thanks, but I think you mean  1+12costsint/5 and not 25?^

And the next step is to derivate the function, put equal to 0, solve for t, and then find the value for x and y?

Comment: denominator is (1+x^2 + y^2)^2 = (1+4)^2 = 25.

Comment: You're right, I missed the last squared sign lol.. But I then got t=pi/4 and x=y=square root of 2, is it correct?

Comment: @Eulersfunction I fixed the typo. Yes, that's how you'd proceed.

Comment: Also sorry my bad, denominator is actually 5, I accidentally added the last square by mistake when I wrote the assignment here.

Comment: Fixed it. Also, since it seems you're new, please consider upvoting an answer if you found it useful.

Comment: I solved b now, I'm on c, but I can't seem to successfully apply lagrange method, any advice?  

Will upvote now.

EDIT:I got too low reputation to upvote..

Comment: Well this in general can be tricky. You have 3 equations $f_x=\lambda g_x$, $f_y=\lambda g_y$ and $g(x,y)=0$, where $g(x,y)=x^2+y^2-4$, with 3 unknowns, $x,y$ and $\lambda$. In this case it might be even harder because the partials of $f$ are messy.

Comment: That's what I did and what I usually do, but in this case it seems very difficult since f is a fraction, I mean it has both a numerator and a denominator, so the 3 equations become very advanced, is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Well, the other method is what you did in part 2. Now, you have to do Lagrange multipliers, so you **have** to solve the system of 3 equations in $x,y,\lambda$.

Comment: It says on C note:the denominator is a constant on the boundary, maybe that helps? But I don't understand what to make of it tbh,,

Comment: The 3rd equation tells you $x^2+y^2=4$, exactly because $x,y$ lie on $C$. You can and should use this, but still you have more work to do.

Comment: I try to simplify it and land at (15y-2x-6x^2y)/25-2xλ=0
 and (15x-2y-6xy^2)/25-2yλ=0

I got 2 equations with 3 variables left..

Comment: but if I multiply the first equation with y and the second one with x I can put them equal to eachother and I arrive at y^2=x^2? But not sure where to go from there.

Comment: This implies $x=y$ or $x=-y$, pretty natural as both the function and the equation of the circle are symmetric in $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Yes, it even matches with the solution I got from b. But this does not give me any critical points, which I assume I am suposed to get?

Comment: What I mean for x=y and x=-y pretty much any number is correct, but maybe I should be thinking since the radius is 2, I can't use nhumbers higher than that, and that is why x=sqrt(2) etc?

Comment: $x$ and $y$ have to satisfy all 3 equations, in particular they have to satisfy $x^2+y^2=4$.

Comment: which they do, if x1=sqrt(2), x2=-sqrt(2), y1=sqrt(2), y2=-sqrt(2)

and that gives us max f(x1,y1)=f(x2,y2)=7/5 and min f(x1,y2)=f(y1,x2)=-1 

Right?

Comment: Sounds right. Remember you can [wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimize+(1%2B3xy)%2F(1%2Bx%5E2%2By%5E2)+on+x%5E2%2By%5E2%3D4) to check your answers.